# How to draw the semicircle whose diameter is the hypotenuse?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw a triangle and rectangle semicircles whose diameters are their legs of this triangle. I can draw the triangle, two semi-circles, but the larger semi-circle still can't. Can anyone help?

How to draw the semicircle whose diameter is the hypotenuse?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}       

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6]
\draw [ultra thick](0,0) rectangle (2,2);
\draw [ultra thick] (0,-1)--(2,-1);
\draw [ultra thick] (-1,0)--(-1,2);
\draw [ultra thick] (3,0)--(3,2);
\draw [ultra thick] (0,3)--(2,3);
\draw [ultra thick] (-1,0)--(-1,2);
\draw [ultra thick,domain=0:90] plot ({2+cos(\x)}, {2+sin(\x)});
\draw [ultra thick,domain=0:-90] plot ({2+cos(\x)}, {sin(\x)});
\draw [ultra thick,domain=180:270] plot ({cos(\x)}, {sin(\x)});
\draw [ultra thick,domain=90:180] plot ({cos(\x)}, {2+sin(\x)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Geometrical diagrams are more easily created if you use the `tkz-euclide` package. The documentation is on CTAN [here](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tkz-euclide) in French, unfortunately. However, you can still puzzle out the details and Google Translate can help when you get stuck.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
\tkzDefPoint(4,0){B}
\tkzDefPoint(4,3){C}
\tkzDefMidPoint(A,B) \tkzGetPoint{M1}
\tkzDrawSector[rotate,ultra thick,draw=red!90,fill=red!20](M1,B)(-180)
\tkzDefMidPoint(B,C) \tkzGetPoint{M2}
\tkzDrawSector[rotate,ultra thick,fill=blue!20](M2,B)(180)
\tkzDefMidPoint(A,C) \tkzGetPoint{M3}
\tkzDrawSector[rotate,ultra thick, draw=black,fill=green!20](M3,C)(180)
\tkzDrawPolygon[ultra thick](A,B,C)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The output, running in Gummi is:
[image]

First lines define the points of the triangle. The midpoint of each side is found and placed into the variable M1, M2, and M3. Each sector is drawn using the macros in the package. Finally, the triangle is draw last for better output.